# Non-aligned pointer being freed, in Java?

Tags: java

This would be simple to track down in Objective-C, but in Java I thought this kind of thing was impossible. The error I'm seeing is:

```
java(7198,0x124a13000) malloc: *** error for object 0x1003109c1: Non-aligned pointer being freed
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

How would I set a breakpoint of this type in Java? Or, how would I track down the object in question? That memory address is NOT the hashCode, right?

Comment: I take it you're compiling Java to C, and then to a binary. What compiler are you using? What happens when you compile your Java code to ordinary Java bytecode, and run it on a JVM?

Comment: It's all 100% standard stuff within Eclipse using the standard JVM. It's probably the CoreMIDI drivers...

Comment: Thanks @AlexD, I tracked it down. It was a native library (supplied by Apple, ironically/sadly).

Comment: All references in Java are aligned by multiples of 8 bytes so the lowest three bits are always 0.  If the lowest bits are not 0 this indicates you have a corrupt reference.

Comment: @PeterLawrey is it possible to create this problem in Java, or must you use JNI to cause it? As I mention in the comments on the answer, it was caused by trying to move sysex messages using the OSX midi implementation.

Comment: You can do this with the Unsafe class, otherwise it has to be in JNI.  Note: if you are using 32-bit references in a 64-bit JVM this won't happen because it drops the lowest three bits (since it knows it will be 000) which is what allows you to have up to 32 GB of heap with 32-bit references.

Comment: Wow, fascinating stuff, thanks @PeterLawrey

Comment: Basically sun.misc.Unsafe lets you do most of things which you are not supposed to do in Java but are useful to be able to do if you want low level programming. e.g. accessing any field in an objects as any type, such as writing an int to a reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't debug this kind of stuff in Java itself, because this seems either a bug in the JVM itself or some rogue native library.

Comment: Yep, it's a rogue library: the CoreMIDI implementation on OSX. Switching to http://www.humatic.de/htools/mmj.htm fixes the problem. So, yeah, nothing to fixed from within Java.